# Praying for someone who has given up

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick

Is it worthwhile to pray for someone who is no longer trying to get a livelihood or be cured of an illness?

Comment: As in "pray for their livelihood/health" or "pray for them to stop giving up"?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92843/is-it-proper-to-daven-for-someone-who-has-no-hope